# empty selectpicker javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I empty a selectpicker with use of javascript? For testing purposes I have two selectpickers, `html` code:

```
 <select id="selectzvlntype" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%">
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Kies type zorgverlener</option>
    <?php
        $q = "SELECT id_zvln_type, zvln_type
             FROM tbl_zvln_types
             ORDER BY zvln_type ASC";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        while($zvln_types = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $zvln_types['id_zvln_type']; ?>"><?php echo $zvln_types['zvln_type']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>  
 </select>
```

`html` code of my second selectpicker:

```
 <select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-size="5" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" id="selectzkh" onchange="ga('send', 'event', 'Select Choice', 'Select ZKH Changed', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value]);">
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Kies uw zorgverlener</option>
    <?php
        $q = "SELECT id_zvln, zvln
             FROM tbl_zvln
             ORDER BY zvln ASC";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        while($zvln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $zvln['id_zvln']; ?>"><?php echo $zvln['zvln']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

My `javascript` code:

```
$(function() {

  $('#selectzvlntype').on('change', function(){
    //var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    //alert(selected);
    $('#selectzkh').empty();
  });

});
```

The alert is working, so the `$('#selectzvlntype').on('change', function()` is working, but the `.empty();` is not..

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Selectpicker component does not refresh itself automatically when you manipulate the DOM element. You need to call `$('#selectzkh').selectpicker("refresh")` method to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bear in mind that once the `selectPicker` plugin is invoked, it hides the original `<select>` element and injects its own `<div>` (along with more elements) to render the actual picker.

That's why calling `empty()` on the original element won't work. You need to use the plugin's own methods to do that:

```
$('#selectzkh').selectpicker('destroy');
```

See [Documentation](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerdestroy)

Answer (score 0):

Try $("#selectzvlntype option").remove(); It should work